# Alias a command that is behind SSH jumpbox

Tags: ssh, alias

In order to run a script, I currently have to do a two step process:

```
ssh remote_machine
./run_script
```

Is it possible to setup an alias on my host machine such that I can execute an alias, for example: `run_script` and it will automatically log me into the remote_machine and run the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, I do this all the time:

```
alias run_script="ssh remote_machine ./run_script"
```

Note that if the `./run_script` script is interactive, you'll need to allocate a TTY using the `-t` flag to `ssh`:

```
alias run_script="ssh -t remote_machine ./run_script"
```

Comment: Also note that if `run_script` is not in the home directory of the user being logged into, you might want to (depending on the script) either `cd` into that directory and/or specify the full path to the script, e. g. `ssh user@remote  'cd /path/to/tools; ./run_script'` or `ssh user@remove /path/to/run_script` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question as I see it is being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a function in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
run_script {
    ssh remote_machine 'sh /path/to/run_script'
}
```

And you can run it just by calling the function name.

```
run_script
```

Comment: How does this run the script on the remote host?

Comment: Updated answer.